# You been denied permission to access this folder.

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, permissions

I have windows 8.1 and windows 7 on 2 different partitions. I have another partition where I keep all my pictures and music on.

When I open that partition up I can access my music but I can't access the pictures folder.

[image]

Not sure what to do or why it is happening. I am the admin on this machine. Can Windows 7 somehow have taken control of that partition and restricted that one folder?

This is kinda concerning as I want to soon remove windows 7 and then I might not be able to get my pictures(I have backups but maybe they are restricted too)

I have not tried today on windows 7 but 2 days ago I could access from windows 7 just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it looks like is happening here is that your user on the Win8 box does not have ownership of the drive that you (presumably) created with a user in Win7.

All you have to do here is:

```
Right-click on the drive/Click 'Properties'/Click the Security
Tab/Click Advanced/

Here you will want to select the 'Owner' tab and then 'Edit'. Form
there you enter your username and select "Replace owner on sub
containers...".

Select 'Apply' and click 'OK' to any messages that popup.
```

This should allow you to access all of the files in the drive from your Win8 user.